# Making AI follow player in pacman game with grid

Tags: c#, sfml

I have an AI that I want to navigate a maze in order to follow the player. I thought of creating a large grid with the help of FloatRects, so I do it like this:

```
private List<FloatRect> grid;
//...
for(int y = 0; y < screenHeight; y += 16)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < screenWidth; x += 16)
    {
        grid.Add(new FloatRect(x, y, 16, 16));
    }
}
```

making each rectangle 16x16. Now I want to make the AI find the path that crosses the least amount of rectangles in order to cross the player, while avoiding walls. How do I approach this?

Comment: Sounds like you want path finding

Comment: Presumably you started by researching [algorithms used in Pac-Man](http://gameinternals.com/post/2072558330/understanding-pac-man-ghost-behavior) and general techniques for [tag:path-finding], including standard graph search methods like A*. What have you tried based on this research so far? Is there a particular step in applying this to your game that you need help with?

Comment: If you prefer video over text, you may find [Pac-Man Ghost AI Explained](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ataGotQ7ir8) useful.